# Why does this command break networking? ip rule add from 0.0.0.0/8 unreachable

Tags: routing, iproute

By chance I found out that `ip rule add from 0.0.0.0/8 unreachable` breaks networking. Not even ping on the same LAN works. I don't understand why.

I remember that the `0.0.0.0/8` IPv4 address block is reserved and may be used only by machines using e.g. DHCP to find its real IP. This is not my case, all hosts are statically configured. I was not expecting to see the `0.0.0.0` address at all. And even with DHCP, such packets are restricted to the current LAN and not routed.

So why that rule prevents regular traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a socket connects (ie: the [`connect(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/connect.2) system call is used) to an IPv4 destination it can:

- either [`bind(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/bind.2) to a specific address before connecting
- or not bind, which is the same as binding to the [INADDR_ANY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0#As_a_host_address) aka 0.0.0.0 used as a placeholder until the actual source address to use is determined.

Normally the various routing entries determine what the source address will ultimately become, since it can't stay 0.0.0.0: either the hinted *src* parameter in the route entry, or the primary address on the interface chosen for this route.

But because of the additional routing *rule* (which could have just been `from 0.0.0.0/32 unreachable` for the same result) the initial route lookup in table *main* will never happen:

```
$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32765:  from 0.0.0.0/8 unreachable
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

The routing rule traversal will stop at entry priority 32765 and never reach the next entry that looks up the *main* routing table. Only bound sockets, including already established connections started without binding the socket before this routing rule was added, since the source address was then updated to an actual address, and their ongoing traffic can still work correctly.

---

Example, assuming the system has the address 192.0.2.2/24 on interface *eth0*, then attempting to connect to 192.0.2.1 on a service listening on 5555/tcp:

```
socat tcp4:192.0.2.1:5555 -
```

will fail because this route lookup now fails:

```
$ ip route get to 192.0.2.1
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

(which is the same as `ip route get from 0.0.0.0 to 192.0.2.1`)

while explictly binding to 192.0.2.2 first will succeed despite the bogus routing rule:

```
socat tcp4:192.0.2.1:5555,bind=192.0.2.2 -
```

for the same reason this route lookup still succeeds:

```
$ ip route get from 192.0.2.2 to 192.0.2.1
192.0.2.1 from 192.0.2.2 dev eth0 uid 1000 
    cache
```

The *from* source won't match the additional routing rule.

If the bogus routing rule wasn't present initially then the first example would have succeeded and the connected socket wouldn't be affected anymore by the bogus routing rule if added later: the 0.0.0.0 address won't appear in any lookup anymore for this connection.

---

Some definitive answers in the kernel sources exist, but it's a bit beyond my ability to follow this thoroughly. Here's what I can tell for the `connect(2)` without `bind(2)`:

- `connect(2)` would use in the end [`ip_route_connect()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/net/route.h?h=v5.4#n296) (eg, in kernel: the [tcp](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c?h=v5.4#n230) or [udp or raw](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/datagram.c?h=v5.4#n48) cases ...) with 0.0.0.0 as wildcard source address to figure out the route and the actual source.
- It will then update the source of the socket with the results from the previous function ([tcp](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c?h=v5.4#n249), [udp or raw](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/datagram.c?h=v5.4#n64) ...).
- But with the bogus routing rule added, `ip_route_connect()` ends up doing a [`fib_rules_lookup()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/core/fib_rules.c?h=v5.4#n275) which will match the 0.0.0.0 source on the *unreachable* rule and will make `connect(2)` fail.

Comment: Great answer. Could you please recommend some sources where could I learn more? Linux Advanced Routing HOWTO document is quite old.

Comment: Old but mostly still relevant (for routing, just forget about the route cache which doesn't exist anymore.) You could check Vincent Bernat's blog for various network-related (or other) topics: https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog